# libspotify API: number of artists and albums resulted from track uri

Tags: spotify

confused - given a track uri, I can get one album but possibly more than one artists (refer to **sp_track_album** and **sp_track_artist**). But given an album, I usually get only one artist. So if I get the album from track uri and then get the artist from album, there would be one artist; if I get the artist directly from track uri, there may be more than one artists. How to explain the difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this album in the Spotify client: `spotify:album:0MYABBSxz6JqujXq2JBvsF`

The artist for that album is "Rihanna".

Some of the tracks on the album are by more than one artist, like "We Found Love" features both Calvin Harris and Rihanna.

An album can only ever be by one artist, while tracks can feature multiple artists. A compilation album typically has an artist of "Various Artists".

Comment: So if multiple artists are returned from **sp_track_artist**, is the first one always the primary artist?

Comment: From what I've observed, I believe so. Especially since defining the "primary artist" can be subjective - a lot of people might argue that both artists are equally responsible for a track, etc.